# Cannot debug program using OpenCV 3.00 and std::vector

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, stdvector

OpenCV is working well either running and debugging. But when I use any std::vector and try to debug the program takes for infinite time at any step, though I can compile and run it. 
I'm on Ubuntu 14 and OpenCV 3.0.0 in debug mode.

This is a code crashing example:

```
#include  "opencv2/highgui.hpp"   
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat img;
    img = imread(argv[1]);
    vector<Mat> test;
    imshow("",img);
    waitKey(-1);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my CmakeLists:

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(test-opencv)

SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE debug)
# Select a default build configuration if none was chosen
IF(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release" CACHE STRING "Choose the type of build, options are: None (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS or CMAKE_C_FLAGS used) Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel." FORCE)
ENDIF()

set (OpenCV_DIR "/usr/local/opencv-3.0.0/")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED PATHS ${OpenCV_DIR})
include_directories (${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})


ADD_EXECUTABLE(test-opencv-executable main.cpp)

IF(OpenCV_FOUND)
  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test-opencv-executable ${OpenCV_LIBS})
ENDIF()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: where does it crash?  run it in a debugger and post the stack trace.

Comment: I do not see any Qt part in your code or CmakeLists. Also, your CmakeLists is incomplete, you should post the complete one that you are using to obtain accurate help. BTW, your `main` does not return anything.

Comment: I have updated the question taking into account you responses. It does not crash, it just takes for infinite and the debugger requires for more time. Thank you